# Template Dynamically Filter Using A String

Tags: django, templates, filter

Let say I have a variable called user_filter_str.

```
user_filter_str = "date:'Y/m/d'|default:'-'"
```

Can I some how apply the user specified filter string to the date value?

```
{{ the_date|user_filter_str }}
```

**Update**:
The user_filter_str is dynamic and can be any thing the user want.

> eg. user_filter_str = "floatformat|my_custom_filter",  user_filter_str =
>   "cut:" "|length" etc.

Comment: you can create a custom template filter to do so

Comment: user_filter_str is not fixed

Comment: yes I imagine so, but the syntax is clearly defined, and with a bit of parsing and such (http://brianwhitmer.blogspot.it/2008/11/how-to-use-django-filters-in-python.html) info maybe you can achieve it

Comment: I think that is a step in the right direction. If I can't find any better alternative I will give that a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is let the user specify the date format, then you can set:

```
user_date_format = 'Y/m/d'
```

Then pass the variable as an argument to the date filter.

```
{{ the_date|date:user_date_format|default:'-' }}
```